# does exp get split in a combo attack

Tags: disgaea

i was leveling up some character in the ice map where every space is red with invincibility except for one green space, i combined all the enemies into one succubus and killed it

at one stage i killed with with a combo attack from my own succubus and kitkat and my succubus was wearing some slippers that had a Statistician whos at level 206 as a test to see if the EXP boost from the Statistician is shared in a combo attack (it it doesn't), in my my succubus levels up by like 6 levels

however when i did the same map but killed my fused enemy with my samurai she did it on her own and she went up by 12 levels, she was equipped with the same item

so i'm wondering is if 2 characters go in for a combo and kill an enemy, since they both get exp is the exp split between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they do. The character who initiates the attack gets a larger chunk, but all characters involved get experience.

Comment: Is this all the same exp (So does the 100 exp get shared 75:25 or is there some bonus exp? 75:50 for example)? Does the assistant get a bonus from a statistician?

Comment: I don't know the details you are looking for. I'm sorry.

Comment: As a caveat, as I understand it, the Triple Experience (if you bought it via the Dark Court) only applies to the first attacker.

Answer (score 1):

In a combo attack, the primary attacker gets 50% of the experience. The remaining 50% are split evenly between the secondary attackers.

When anyone has an exp bonus from a Statistician specialist in one of their items, this bonus is applied to their share of the experience only.